# Excluding the arrow pattern "->" using grep

Tags: git, bash, grep

I'm trying to list all the Git remote branches I have using

```
git branch -r
```

This unfortunately also gives me

```
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
```

I'm using a shell script with a `for` to loop through the branch names. It treats `origin/HEAD`, `->` and `origin/master` as separate branch names, causing an error. To avoid this, I'm using `grep -v` to filter out the `->`

```
for x in $(git branch -r | grep -v '->')
do #stuff
done;
```

But my `grep -v '->'` doesn't work. Neither do `\-\>` or `^->` (I'm not very proficient with regexes)

How do I accomplish what I need? (Either in Git, by not outputting the `origin/HEAD -> origin/master` in the first place, or in `grep`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use plumbing commands when scripting:

```
git show-ref |grep remotes/origin
```

`git show-ref` lists all branches, tags, then filter with origin

You get SHA1s and prefixes in the output, to get rid of it use

```
git show-ref |grep remotes/origin| cut -d" " -f 2 | cut -d/ -f 3-
```

The first `cut` removes hashes from the list, and the second `cut` removes the `refs/remotes`

Comment: +1 for showing me how to do it the right way. I read in another answer that I should be using plumbing commands but was intimidated by them

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried `grep -v '\->'`

I think you have to scape only the dash.

Answer (score 6):

Quick thing for grep:

```
grep -e expr
```

allows `expr` to resemble options without being interpreted *as* options.  So you can find occurrences of `-e` with `grep -e -e`, or skip `->` with `grep -v -e '->'`.

General rule for git: for scripting with references, use the [`git for-each-ref`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-for-each-ref.html) command.

Answer (score 4):

Most gnu tools support `--` for end of options, which is exactly for this kind of cases.

You can write:

```
grep -v -- ->
```

Comment: The most simple and elegant solution in my opinion, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

You were so close:

```
for x in $(git branch -r | grep -v '\->')
```

Comment: This actually answers the question as asked in the title, i.e. grep related not git related. It should not be downvoted just because it doesn't mention git. (I got here by googling "grep ->".)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your grep command with this sed command.

```
sed s'+^.*\-\>.*$++g'
```

Quick explanation:

The delimiters are the + character.  So am replacing ^.*->.* with an empty string.

^ = start of line

.*= any characters

-> the pattern of interest

.*= any other character sequence

$= end of line